# How to import data from API to use as Fuse list in Vue app

Tags: vue.js, fuse.js

I'm trying to filter-on-search a list in Vue js using Fuse js fuzzy search. I can get it working when the list is entered as a data property, but not when I get it via a JSON api.

I'm working on an e-commerce website, and want the main page to have a list of products, with a search input field at the top. When the search input field is empty, all products should be visible. Once the user starts typing, the products array should be filtered based on what they type.

It's working when I add the products array manually into the data properties on the Vue instance, but when I try to call a JSON api using axios to get the data instead, I can't the search function to work.

I'm fairly certain the issue is to do with the lifecycle and asynchronous functions, but, despite reading up on these yesterday, my grasp of these more complex issues is pretty poor. I've tried abstracting the axios GET to a method and then calling that in mounted(), pulling it in as a computed property, and various other rearrangements of the furniture, but I'm stumped.

[Here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wRXgEy) with the search working as a manually entered array on the instance.

```
window.Fuse = Fuse;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    var options = {
      shouldSort: true,
      threshold: 0.6,
      location: 0,
      distance: 100,
      maxPatternLength: 32,
      minMatchCharLength: 1,
      keys: [
        "title",
        "author.firstName"
      ]
    };
    this.fuse = new window.Fuse(this.list, options);
    this.result = this.list
  },
  watch: {
    search() {
      if (this.search.trim() === '')
        this.result = this.list
      else
        this.result = this.fuse.search(this.search.trim())
    }
  },
  data: {
    fuse: null,
    search: '',
    list: [{
      title: "Old Man's War",
      author: {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Scalzi"
      },{....
    }]
    result: []
  }
});
```

If anyone could demonstrate how the same result would be achieved but via an api call, I'd be very grateful as I'm pretty stuck and it's driving me mad. An accompanying explanation would also be incredibly valuable.

Comment: So when you are rendering your products, what are you iterating? result or list or fuse? So what does your v-for say? And I mean when you make the api call.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll give you a working pen, more of a proof of concept than anything else.

https://codepen.io/rifi2k/pen/wRXpWE

```
Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    var options = {
      shouldSort: true,
      threshold: 0.6,
      location: 0,
      distance: 100,
      maxPatternLength: 32,
      minMatchCharLength: 1,
      keys: [
        "name",
        "email"
      ]
    };
    
    this.$http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      this.list = response.data;
      this.fuse = new window.Fuse(this.list, options);
      this.result = this.list
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err)
    });

  },
  watch: {
    search() {
      if (this.search.trim() === '')
        this.result = this.list
      else
        this.result = this.fuse.search(this.search.trim())
    }
  },
  data: {

    fuse: null,
    search: '',
    list: [],
    result: []

  }

});
```

So for starters you don't need to put the fuse library into the window because including the script from the CDN will already take care of that for you.

We are going to use the [Vue prototype to set the global axios](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html) to $http. This way you can use it in any Vue component with `this.$http`

Then we are going to make a GET request to our API with axios which returns a promise with our response which contains the JSON data. [We can use promise .then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) to make sure we are waiting until the API has returned us the data. Then we stick all the rest of the work depending on the API call being finished inside of the promise .then so that it cannot run until we have our data.

Also a more modern way to do this would be [Async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) [Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).